# Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza found

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dependencies, manifest

These are my dependencies in manifest file

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0"
```

I am getting error

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
```

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

> Note: Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.

Only use specific libraries, example:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
```

Comment: How cam I find relavant libraries

Comment: you add the library that you want to use in your application

Comment: You can find the libraries here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Having the same issue, but In my project don't have any of this line.  
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'